Voronoi Like Circles/Line Renderer Issue
When lined up across the X axis
When lined up across the Y axis
I have a circle prefab. This circle is a line-renderer in the shape of a circle. This is what my script attached to those prefabs does:

Find Nearby Circles

Sort Nearby Circles by Angle: use Mathf.Atan2() to calculate the angle between each nearby circle(s) and the current circle

Cull "Squeezed" Circles: For each circle in the sorted nearby flag list, we check if it's squeezed between two others by comparing the distances between the circles

Find Intersections Between Circles: calculate the intersections between each circle with current circle

Flatten the Curve Between Intersection Points: modifies the circle by linearly interpolating between the two intersection points, creating a straight edge between them.

Repeat the process for multiple intersection


As you can see from the images,  I'm only flattening the wrong side when the two share a Z axis. And it's not both, its always the one with the lesser X value.
A little snippet of related code:
private void FlattenBetweenIntersections(Vector3 intersection1, Vector3 intersection2)
{
    float angle1 = GetAngleFromCenter(intersection1);
    float angle2 = GetAngleFromCenter(intersection2);

    if (angle1 > angle2)
    {
        float temp = angle1;
        angle1 = angle2;
        angle2 = temp;
    }

    FlattenCurveBetweenAngles(angle1, angle2);
}

private void FlattenCurveBetweenAngles(float angle1, float angle2)
{
    float angleStep = 360f / segments;
    int startIndex = Mathf.RoundToInt(angle1 / angleStep);
    int endIndex = Mathf.RoundToInt(angle2 / angleStep);

    Vector3 startPos = lineRenderer.GetPosition(startIndex);
    Vector3 endPos = lineRenderer.GetPosition(endIndex);

    for (int i = startIndex + 1; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        float t = (float)(i - startIndex) / (endIndex - startIndex);
        Vector3 newPos = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, t);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, newPos);
    }
}

Full code below:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FlagController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float AOI = 25f;  // Max Area of Influence (radius)
    public int segments = 50; // Number of segments for the circle
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    // Unique identifier for each flag
    public string flagID;

    private static int flagCounter = 0; // Static counter to generate unique IDs

    private void Start()
    {
        // Assign a unique ID based on the flagCounter
        flagID = "Flag_" + flagCounter++;

        // Setup the LineRenderer component
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if (lineRenderer == null)
        {
            lineRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        }

        // Set up the basic circle
        lineRenderer.positionCount = segments + 1;
        lineRenderer.useWorldSpace = false;
        lineRenderer.loop = true;
        lineRenderer.widthMultiplier = 0.2f;

        // Generate the initial circular boundary
        GenerateAOIBoundary();

        // Find nearby flags automatically
        List<FlagController> nearbyFlags = FindNearbyFlags();

        // Sort by angle
        SortByAngle(nearbyFlags);

        // Cull squeezed flags
        CullSqueezedFlags(ref nearbyFlags);

        // Now calculate the Voronoi AOI based on nearby flags
        if (nearbyFlags.Count > 0)
        {
            CalculateVoronoiAOI(nearbyFlags);
        }
    }

    // Generates the initial circular boundary for the flag
    public void GenerateAOIBoundary()
    {
        float angleStep = 360f / segments;
        for (int i = 0; i <= segments; i++)
        {
            float angle = i * angleStep * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
            float x = Mathf.Cos(angle) * AOI;
            float z = Mathf.Sin(angle) * AOI;
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, 0f, z));
        }
    }

    // Find all nearby flags within a certain distance
    private List<FlagController> FindNearbyFlags()
    {
        List<FlagController> nearbyFlags = new List<FlagController>();

        // Get all flags in the scene
        FlagController[] allFlags = FindObjectsOfType<FlagController>();

        // Loop through and find flags within a certain distance
        foreach (FlagController otherFlag in allFlags)
        {
            if (otherFlag != this)  // Ignore self
            {
                float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, otherFlag.transform.position);
                if (distance < 2 * AOI)
                {
                    nearbyFlags.Add(otherFlag);
                }
            }
        }

        return nearbyFlags;
    }

    // Sort the nearby flags by angle relative to the current flag
    private void SortByAngle(List<FlagController> nearbyFlags)
    {
        nearbyFlags.Sort((a, b) =>
        {
            float angleA = Mathf.Atan2(a.transform.position.z - transform.position.z, a.transform.position.x - transform.position.x);
            float angleB = Mathf.Atan2(b.transform.position.z - transform.position.z, b.transform.position.x - transform.position.x);
            return angleA.CompareTo(angleB);
        });
    }

    // Cull flags that are squeezed out by others
    private void CullSqueezedFlags(ref List<FlagController> nearbyFlags)
    {
        bool finishedCulling = false;
        while (!finishedCulling && nearbyFlags.Count >= 3)
        {
            finishedCulling = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < nearbyFlags.Count; i++)
            {
                FlagController flagA = GetLooped(nearbyFlags, i - 1);
                FlagController flagB = GetLooped(nearbyFlags, i);
                FlagController flagC = GetLooped(nearbyFlags, i + 1);

                if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, flagB.transform.position) > Vector3.Distance(flagA.transform.position, flagC.transform.position) &&
                    Vector3.Distance(flagA.transform.position, flagC.transform.position) > Vector3.Distance(flagA.transform.position, flagB.transform.position) &&
                    Vector3.Distance(flagA.transform.position, flagC.transform.position) > Vector3.Distance(flagB.transform.position, flagC.transform.position))
                {
                    nearbyFlags.RemoveAt(i);
                    finishedCulling = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Calculate the Voronoi area of influence, considering nearby flags
    public void CalculateVoronoiAOI(List<FlagController> nearbyFlags)
    {
        List<Vector3> intersections = new List<Vector3>();

        foreach (FlagController nearbyFlag in nearbyFlags)
        {
            Vector3 intersection1, intersection2;
            if (FindIntersections(this, nearbyFlag, out intersection1, out intersection2))
            {
                intersections.Add(intersection1);
                intersections.Add(intersection2);
            }
        }

        if (intersections.Count == 0)
        {
            GenerateAOIBoundary();  // No intersections, keep the full circle
        }
        else
        {
            FlattenCurveForIntersections(intersections);
        }
    }

    // Find intersections between two flags' AOIs
    private bool FindIntersections(FlagController flag1, FlagController flag2, out Vector3 intersection1, out Vector3 intersection2)
    {
        intersection1 = Vector3.zero;
        intersection2 = Vector3.zero;

        float d = Vector3.Distance(flag1.transform.position, flag2.transform.position);
        if (d > flag1.AOI + flag2.AOI || d < Mathf.Abs(flag1.AOI - flag2.AOI))
        {
            return false; // No valid intersection
        }

        float a = (flag1.AOI * flag1.AOI - flag2.AOI * flag2.AOI + d * d) / (2 * d);
        float h = Mathf.Sqrt(flag1.AOI * flag1.AOI - a * a);

        Vector3 direction = (flag2.transform.position - flag1.transform.position).normalized;
        Vector3 p2 = flag1.transform.position + a * direction;

        intersection1 = new Vector3(p2.x + h * direction.z, flag1.transform.position.y, p2.z - h * direction.x);
        intersection2 = new Vector3(p2.x - h * direction.z, flag1.transform.position.y, p2.z + h * direction.x);

        return true;
    }

    // Flatten the curve between two intersection points
    private void FlattenCurveForIntersections(List<Vector3> intersections)
    {
        intersections.Sort((a, b) => GetAngleFromCenter(a).CompareTo(GetAngleFromCenter(b)));

        for (int i = 0; i < intersections.Count; i += 2)
        {
            Vector3 intersection1 = intersections[i];
            Vector3 intersection2 = intersections[i + 1];
            FlattenBetweenIntersections(intersection1, intersection2);
        }
    }

    // Helper function to get the angle from the center of the current flag
    private float GetAngleFromCenter(Vector3 point)
    {
        Vector3 relativePoint = point - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(relativePoint.z, relativePoint.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        if (angle < 0)
        {
            angle += 360f;
        }

        return angle;
    }

    // Helper function to flatten the curve between two intersection points
    private void FlattenBetweenIntersections(Vector3 intersection1, Vector3 intersection2)
    {
        float angle1 = GetAngleFromCenter(intersection1);
        float angle2 = GetAngleFromCenter(intersection2);

        if (angle1 > angle2)
        {
            float temp = angle1;
            angle1 = angle2;
            angle2 = temp;
        }

        FlattenCurveBetweenAngles(angle1, angle2);
    }

    // Main function to flatten a curve between two angles
    private void FlattenCurveBetweenAngles(float angle1, float angle2)
    {
        Debug.Log("{flagID} {angle1} {angle2}");
        float angleStep = 360f / segments;
        int startIndex = Mathf.RoundToInt(angle1 / angleStep);
        int endIndex = Mathf.RoundToInt(angle2 / angleStep);

        Vector3 startPos = lineRenderer.GetPosition(startIndex);
        Vector3 endPos = lineRenderer.GetPosition(endIndex);

        for (int i = startIndex + 1; i < endIndex; i++)
        {
            float t = (float)(i - startIndex) / (endIndex - startIndex);
            Vector3 newPos = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, t);
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, newPos);
        }
    }

    // Helper function to get a looped element from the list
    private FlagController GetLooped(List<FlagController> list, int index)
    {
        return list[(index + list.Count) % list.Count];
    }
}

My most recent attempt took the center point of the circle, and also got the positions it thought it was going to move the circle (line renderer) to and checked if the center point was in that, if not then we reversed the angles sent but that didn't change anything.
My issue is in the images. When they share a Y axis the code doesn't properly build the circle with the lesser X value. It puts the remaining circle on the wrong side. The lines in the right location.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@JesseJohnson I believe expected result is the first image, but OP is asking about the second image case where it is failing

Instead of angles .. wouldn't it be easier to just get the vector between both centers if the circles .. and then use Cross in order to get a 90° (perpendicular) vector on it which would be the one you want to align the according points to .. the exact intersection you can then simply get by the two radius of the circles (assuming they might not always have the same)

@derHugo I have tried this and the code still functions the same
